# Chef is not able to resolve my cookbooks name. Even the name is wrong

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to run one of my recipes in a cookbook. chef is not able to find it. Below is my tree. The command that I tried is

```
sudo chef-client --local-mode -runlist "recipe[apache::server]"
```

I even tried with the path of the cookbook

```
sudo chef-client --local-mode -runlist "recipe[cookbooks/apache::server]"
```

Below is the error that I get. The strange part is that the name of the cookbook that it shows in the error is `unlist` which is not the name of my cookbook. My cookbook name is `apache`.

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo chef-client --local-mode -runlist "recipe[apache::server]"
[2017-06-18T07:24:32+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line, using command line options.
Starting Chef Client, version 12.14.89
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["unlist"]

================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: unlist

Expanded Run List:
------------------
* unlist

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux


Running handlers:
[2017-06-18T07:24:34+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2017-06-18T07:24:34+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 01 seconds
[2017-06-18T07:24:34+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /root/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-06-18T07:24:34+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-06-18T07:24:34+00:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"
[2017-06-18T07:24:34+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Tree Structure

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ tree
.
|-- cookbooks
|   `-- apache
|       |-- Berksfile
|       |-- chefignore
|       |-- metadata.rb
|       |-- README.md
|       |-- recipes
|       |   |-- default.rb
|       |   `-- server.rb
|       |-- spec
|       |   |-- spec_helper.rb
|       |   `-- unit
|       |       `-- recipes
|       |           |-- default_spec.rb
|       |           `-- server_spec.rb
|       `-- test
|           `-- recipes
|               |-- default_test.rb
|               `-- server.rb
|-- delete.rb
|-- hello.rb
|-- hellotodelet.rb
`-- nodes
    `-- localhost.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was you had `-runlist` with one dash, you need two dashes: `--runlist`.

Comment: Yep, I identified that later and realized my mistake. Thnx

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I found the answer but partially. So I already executed the recipe individually without using the `runlist`. So the package was installed and the service was up and running.

```
sudo chef-client --local-mode cookbooks/apache/server.rb
```

So it wasn't working. Not sure why though. I thought the recipes were meant to be idempotent. Anyway, so later I wrote another recipe to uninstall and disable the package & service. When I re-ran the `server.rb`, it worked.

Still not sure though y it wasn't able to pick the first time. Running it again and again makes it work the same way though. So there must be some difference between executing a single recipe and executing a recipe from the cookbook.

Comment: This is not correct, you just side stepped the issue.